# Setup Blackberry Development Environment on Java + Linux + eclipse juno

Tags: java, linux, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Hi I have to setup an **Blackberry Development** for **Java** on **Linux** machine with **Eclipse Juno**.
I have tried to set up using ejde for eclipse using Blackberry Updates for eclipse using MAC URL but it not works, I don't found URL for Linux its only for Windows and MAC

then I have tried to setup an environment using steps given in [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Eclipse-JDE-Plugin-Linux-a-working-environment/td-p/192473) post of blackberry forum but still I don't able to set up an environment

can any one help me to setup en environment or any links that can help me thanks

Comment: You could always install a windows virtual machine.

Comment: @Mister Smith I have shifted to windows machine but still getting error while Installing S/w on eclipse

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,net.rim.EclipseJDE,2.0.0.201207181003. MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 2a0e8e89aa2d6464b0e1422251c6e60a and found 2506d6b04a64d414b2e90e2c1bffbf19.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..your logs say artifacts not found and so I guess you're using the eclipse blackberry plugin update site to download the jde which unfortunately is no more supported by blackberry. You'll need to download the blackberry eclipse jde bundle that is pre installed with blackberry jde. [**Check this out**](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/download/#jde).

Moreover I haven't seen any support for linux yet.